# git requests for master branch changes

Tags: git

Lets assume we have a group of people working on project in one git repo. Each of them works on his own branch(es), then he makes a merge of the master branch with his own and so on.

Is it possible to forbid any direct changes of the master branch (such as commits, merges), and make something like a request for changes of this branch, which will be applied after all members of the team (or one particular person) accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make push request like on GitHub there is few options: 

1. First of all you should prohibit push into master branch (using git hooks) and assign some person as "mayor of master branch" with permission to push into it and other devs should send push request to mayor. So, in this case each dev, who wants to make push into master branch, could use `git format-patch` for sending patch by email to mayor and then mayor, using `git am` could apply that patch on master. Also patches could be formed from `git diff` command and send by email in text format or as *.patch file. In this case mayor could use `git apply` to apply *.patch file to master branch.

2. You could use similar to GitHub tools like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943321/github-like-site-for-internal-use

Hope this answer will help you :)